# Export mongoose query function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im making script in my app, that will work not on routes, but always active.
I did another controller file, but faced to the problem. My module.exports doesnt work with mongoose query, i mean, nothing happens. Others  operations works. What did i do wrong?

```
const Model = require("model");

module.exports = () => {

    setInterval(() => {
        console.log('interval');
    }, 2000);

    Model.findOne({name: 'test'}).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

'interval' is showing, and result is not. In my other app i did the same thing and its works without problem! Ofcourse these apps has different architecture, but still... Can't find answer in google.

UPDATE

I have the mongoose connection listener

```
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log("connected");
});
```

Tried to put code above there, and it doesnt work either.

Comment: And what it should do ?

Comment: Well, find some specific files by names in model and remove it with cron schedule job.

Comment: Can you provide all the code, and how you use it ?

Comment: Try updating your import to use a relative path: const Model = require("./model");

Comment: Ok, just a little update. All day long trying to fix it. I have a lot of models, And all models work with this code, but User model is dont. User model is Ok, all other controllers works perfectly with it. For User model works only update function User.update({}) ... it returns ok:0, but if i add query User,update({name: 'name'})... it stop working again. It's really driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

Well first thing that I see is if you want to run your query at the 2 second interval you should put the logic in interior of the `setInterval`'s `callback`:

```
setInterval(() => {
  console.log('interval');

  Model.findOne({ name: 'test' }).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

}, 2000);
```

to be able to debug your script you can attach a handler for `uncaughtException`

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.error(`Caught exception: ${err}`);
});
```

Comment: Yea, i understand this syntax :) just show above these 2 functions only for example. Your code doesnt work either. FindOne function doesnt work at all.

Comment: Did you checked if you have a database connection ?

Comment: Put handler in my script, nothing happened :/